# How to access the printer from within wine

Tags: 11.10, wine, printing

How can I have access to my printer from within Wine so I can use for example Office 2003 to print something. The print already works in Ubuntu but am looking into using it from wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some versions ago, Wine automatically offers to print in any printer already configured in Ubuntu. My confusion was that I did not see it in the Office 2003 that I was emulating in Wine and this was because I did not have it actually connected to the laptop.

So If you do not see the printer in the emulated program it is most likely that it is not actually connected to PC. Connect the printer and Ubuntu will work it's magic with it. Then you can automatically use it in Wine.

I also did not have to install any drivers in Wine to work with it.

Comment: ... well done for finding this - can you accept your answer please to close this question?

Comment: Well not a very smart answer I must say. Did not notice that "problem". But it normally takes me 2 days to accept my own answer for my own question. It took 2 hours this time.

Comment: Well I thought is was good - i didnt know that wine printed via ubuntu printing stuff :)