# Word on PlayonLinux does not recognise printer

Tags: wine, printing, playonlinux, microsoft-word

I would like to print from Microsoft Word running through PlayonLinux / Wine, but Word tells me that no printers are installed.
However, my HP Deskjet F 4500 - which is linked up via USB -  works on other software such as LibreOffice Writer.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I am just starting out on Linux.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

The WineHQ documentation for [other things to configure](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure) points out that `wine` will use CUPS.  You should install `libcups2`, and potentially `libcups2:i386`:

1. `sudo apt-get install libcups2`

If you want to be able to print to a `.pdf` file, you'll need `cups-pdf`:

1. `sudo apt-get install cups-pdf`

Otherwise, you may be experiencing [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87717/how-to-access-the-printer-from-within-wine), where you need to have to printer plugged in for it to actually work.

Comment: Hi earthmeLon.  Thanks for your reply.  However, I have installed all three of the above, and made sure the printer is plugged in, but Word still says "no printer is installed".  As mentioned above, I can print from LibreWriter, so I presume CUPS is installed and working.  Laurence

Comment: Will you double check that it's installed and working?  CUPS isn't the only printing system.  Specifically, you need `lpr` if you're going the non-BSD route.  Will you edit your question and tell us how the printer is hooked up (USB, Serial, Network)?

Comment: If you mean check that CUPS is installed and working, I was able to do this at [link] (http://localhost:631/admin) - CUPS web interface - previously, but now get message "unable to connect".  When I previously was able to access the CUPS web interface it confirmed my printer was recognised / installed.  I don't know if 1pr is installed and I don't know what a "non-BSD route" is.

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing CUPS, still had no printing, so after researching printing files structure etc, I've found an solution! It seems that some distro doesn't point to the right printcap file.. So, tha's what I did:

First, make sure you have CUPS installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install cups cups-pdf
```

then, if you have it, backup original printcap

```
 sudo mv  /etc/printcap /etc/printcap.bkp
```

now create a symlink to the CUPS' printcap. In my case it was at /var/run/cups/

```
 ln -s /var/run/cups/printcap /etc/printcap
```

Hope it fix things to you guys

Comment: Hi Eduardo.  The first command confirmed that I have the latest version of CUPS installed.  Neither of the other 2 commands worked on my system.

Comment: "In my case it was ar /var/run/cups/". How would I find where the CUPS printcap is on my system?